# ¿Por qué la redirección no funciona en una carpeta en específico en Wordpress local? Error "Unsupported SSL request"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Mediante [WP Cli](https://wp-cli.org/es/) he pasado con suma facilidad mi instalación Wordpress remota a mi entorno local siguiendo los pasos indicados en [esta guía](https://rocketgeek.com/basics/using-wp-cli-to-migrate-copy-your-site/).

Lo que es Wordpress **funciona perfectamente**. Pero, aparte de eso, yo tengo montada en el servidor remoto una API **que funciona independiente de Wordpress, pero que usa tablas de la misma base de datos que usa Wordpress**.

En el servidor remoto funciona sin problema ninguno, pero en mi entorno local no.

Las URL son más o  menos.

En el entorno remoto, que funciona:

```
https://midominio.com/api/version/endPoint/unDato
```

En el entorno local, no funciona, me da un error 404:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/version/endPoint/unDato
```

Para las redirecciones, tengo los siguientes archivos `.htaccess` en el entorno remoto:

#### En la carpeta `api`:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

En la carpeta **`version`**:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

En el entorno local, he puesto los mismos archivos, pero quitando esta línea:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Y poniendo esta línea así:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

El 404 me lo muestra dentro del entorno de Wordpress, es decir, como una página no encontrada, con el tema y todo, mientras que en remoto, si pongo la URL en el navegador, me sale un JSON con la respuesta de la API, que es lo que quiero que haga también en local.

Es evidente que lo que ocurre es que no está reconociendo el `.htaccess` de redirección en el entorno local.

He intentando también con cosas como:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

También he probado poniéndolo tal cual está en el entorno remoto (con `https`) sin ningún resultado satisfactorio.

Estoy usando WP Cli también para iniciar el servidor con el comando:

```
wp server
```

La salida por consola es:

```
[Fri Dec  1 13:04:11 2023] PHP 8.3.0 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
```

Cuando navego a cualquier URL del sitio Wordpress funciona, pero si voy una URL de la API tengo el 404 y en la consola estos mensajes:

```
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50964 Accepted 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50964 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request) 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50964 Closing 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50965 Accepted 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50965 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)  
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50965 Closing 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50966 Accepted
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50966 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request) 
[Fri Dec 1 13:05:36 2023] [::1]:50966 Closing
```

¿Cómo podría resolver esto? ¿Por qué en remoto redirige bien y en local no?

#### Edit

Contenido de `wp-config.php`:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '***');
define('DB_USER', '***');

define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', false);

define('AUTH_KEY',         '***');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '***');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '***');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '***');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '***');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '***');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '***');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '***');

$table_prefix  = 'wp_***_';
define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300 );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 7 );
define( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 120 );

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Según entiendo, en tu entorno local deberías comentar las 2 líneas, de lo contrario estarías realizando una redirección infinita. Quizas una buena idea sería hacer el control del HTTPS solo cuand no estas en `localhost` y así evitarte tener que comentar esas lineas

Comment: @Marcos ¿Te refieres a comentar esta línea: `RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]`?

Comment: Si es para pruebas y tiene problemas con el **https** no se ha planteado "virtualizar" su entorno con ngrok?

Comment: @OCHOA realmente la idea es trasladar a local el entorno de desarrollo, para tener una copia local y además modificar y probar en local y luego subirlo a producción en remoto usando git. Anteriormente yo cambiaba todo directamente en remoto, pero es más lento y cuando había errores se veían en producción hasta que eran corregidos. Y cuando tocaba cambiar de hosting era algo muy tedioso. De ngrok no tengo ni idea.

Comment: @A.Cedano, exacto, esa linea debería comentarla. En tu entorno local, si comentas `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`, esa no tiene sentido que este

Comment: **ngrok** le hace una VPN a su entorno local y se la publica en internet. Es super fácil usarlo, baja el .exe y ejecuta un comando y listo, su proyecto existe en una url única suya, viva mientras usted tiene corriendo el proceso. Yo lo uso para ver temas de https desde mi ambiente local

Comment: @Marcos agregado al final de la pregunta.

Comment: @Marcos corrigiendo el error de las comillas en `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` y en `FORCE_SSL`, el problema persiste.

Comment: @A.Cedano, encontre [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDAX1uQzM8Y) en ingles. Creo que puede darte la solución que estas necesitando.

Comment: @Marcos aunque ahora no aparece el error *`Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)`*.

Comment: ¿Puerto 8080? ¿Es Tomcat y/o Apache en local/remoto? ¿Difieren los entornos? ¿Has considerado https local con un certificado auto-firmado?

Comment: @Sal es el puerto en el que inicia por defecto cuando ejecuto el comando `wp server` (estoy usando WP Cli y tengo MAMP en Mac Os X). Creo haber instalado un certificado local siguiendo [estas instrucciones](https://web.dev/articles/how-to-use-local-https?hl=es), gracias a lo que Marcos me ha referido en un comentario anterior. Pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. El certificado se crea, pero no veo forma de iniciar el servidor local en `https` (como dice el enlace), siempre me inicia en `http`.

Comment: El servidor web interconstruido de PHP [no soporta .htaccess](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/server/).

Comment: Para un [certificado auto-firmado en MacOS](https://superuser.com/questions/73979/how-to-easily-create-a-ssl-certificate-and-configure-it-in-apache2-in-mac-os-x) no hay necesidad de instalar tanto, ya que incluye OpenSSL.

Comment: @A.Cedano según entiendo `wp server` lo que en realidad hace es ejecutar el servidor [`built-in`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) de `PHP`. Dicho servidor NO soporta `HTTPS` por lo que es necesario utilizar otra forma para "re-rutear" con `HTTPS`. Como te comentamos antes, `ngrok` o `stunnel` son 2 opciones. Pero tenes que tener ambos procesos correindo. Otra forma es utilizar otro webserver, por ejemplo , `Apache`, `ngnix`, etc. Si va a usar otro webserver, entonces no tenes que usar `wp server` para ver tu sitio.

Comment: @Marcos he intentado varias cosas sin ningún resultado. Al final lo que hice fue separar la parte de la API, probándola en un contexto normal, fuera de Wordpress. Y es que cuando lograba hacer que funcione con `https` los links de Wordpress no me funcionaban, y cuando probaba con `wp server` los links sí funcionaban perfectamente, pero entonces la API no funcionaba. Agradezco enormente tu interés en este problema. Un cordial saludo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, en mi caso, cuando necesito desarrollar y probar sitios en HTTPS, a diferencia tuya, utilizo XAMPP. Para cada sitio agrego un vitural-host en la configuración de `Apache` con el mismo dominio que tiene en produccion (_creo un certificado local para cada uno_), modifico mi archivo `hosts` para que resuelva en `127.0.0.1` y los corro como si estuviera en producción. Y cuando necesito probar un `webhook` de alguna plataforma externar, utilizo `ngrok`. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos el problema es que mi equipo está basado en el chip de Apple, y no puedo usar XAMPP sin pasar por Rosetta, cosa que no quiero.